# How to fix 500 Internal Server Error / web.py

Tags: python, pymongo, web.py

I got this Error, I am trying to create a simple web project using web.py unfortunately when I try to register a user I got the error and I have tried already to change the attributes but no way to fix the problem

```
File "C:\Users\Pippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web\utils.py", line 75, in   __getattr__
    return self[key]
KeyError: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 257, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Pippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 248, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "C:\Users\Pippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 488, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "C:\Users\Pippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 466, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "controller.py", line 57, in POST
    reg_model.insert_user(data)
  File "C:\Users\Pippo\Desktop\UDEMY\The Complete Python 3 Course - Beginner to Advanced\Web development project Using web.py\CodeWizzard\Models\RegisterModel.py", line 15, in insert_user
    id = self.Users.insert({"username": data.username, "name": data.name, "password": hashed,
  File "C:\Users\Pippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web\utils.py", line 77, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(k)
AttributeError: 'name'


127.0.0.1:55572 - - [15/Aug/2019 20:54:31] "HTTP/1.1 POST /postregistration" - 500 Internal Server Error
```

---

I have already check the files (Main.py, RegistrationModel.py and Register.HTML) and I don´t find the Error.

```
urls = (
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/login', 'Login',
    '/logout', 'Logout',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration',
)


app = web.application(urls, globals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore("session"), initializer={"user": None})
session_data = session._initializer

render = web.template.render("Views/Templates", base = "Main",
                         globals={'session': session_data, 'current_user': session_data["user"]})


class PostRegistration:

  def POST(self):
    data = web.input()

    reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
    reg_model.insert_user(data)

    return data.username

'''
RegistrationModel.py
'''

class RegisterModel:

  def __init__(self):
      self.client = MongoClient()
      self.db = self.client.codewizard
      self.Users = self.db.users

  def insert_user(self, data):
      hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(data.password.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())

      id = self.Users.insert({"username": data.username, "name":   data.name, "password": hashed,
                            "email": data.email, "avatar": "", "background": "", "about": "",
                            "hobbies": "", "birthday": ""})
   print("uid is", id)

'''
Register.html
'''

<div class = "container">
<h2>Register Account</h2>
<br /><br />

<form id="register-form">
    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input name = "username" id = "username" class = "form-control" type = "text" placeholder = "Choose a username" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
        <label for="display_name" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
        <input name = "display_name" id = "display_name" class = "form-control" type = "text" placeholder = "Enter your full name" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
        <input name = "email" id = "email" class = "form-control" type = "email" placeholder = "Enter your email" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
        <input name = "password" id = "password" class = "form-control" type = "password" placeholder = "Make a password" />
    </div>

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info waves-effect">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any ideas why I am having this Error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like your `data` object doesn't have a `name` variable. Also, can you edit your post so the error is in triple ticks, so it looks like code, and also add some details? I tried to edit it, but don't know which details to add.

Comment: in `RegistrationModel.py` you use `data.name` which makes problem. It seems `data` doesn't have field `name`. And in your form I don't see `<input>` with `name="name"` but `name="display_name"`. Try `data.display_name` instead of `data.name`

Comment: @Manson Caiby first thanks for the edition!

Comment: @furas thank you very much for the help, the problem was in fact in the register.html I just change `name = "display_name"` to `name = "name"` and now it works! 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the you are not passing `name` in the payload of the POST request.

You can either use the `forms` module to validate the input.

http://webpy.org/cookbook/forms

Or specify default values to `web.input` if `name` is an optional input.

```
data = web.input(name="default-name")
```